# PHP Convert word to html with COM

Tags: php, html, com, ms-word

```
$file='C:/a.doc';
$saveas=__DIR__.'/tmp/a.html';
$word=new COM('word.application');
$document=$word->Documents->Open($file);
$document->SaveAs($saveas,8);
$word->Quit();
$word=null;
echo file_get_contents($saveas);
@unlink($saveas);
```

It works fine in PHP CLI mode(php -f "com_server.php"), but when I run it through web(windows/apache http://localhost/com_server.php), an error occurred:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed
>   to create COM object `word.application': Server execution failed' in
>   D:\www\wwwroot\com_server.php:16 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\www\wwwroot\com_server.php(16): com->com('word.applicatio...') #1
>   {main} thrown in D:\www\wwwroot\com_server.php on line 16

I've also tried to wrap the code in shell_exec, but same error as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If Apache is running as a different user, then it might not have privilege to run MSWord

Comment: Have ran apache service as same user, still not lucky, error as below:


Fatal error: Call to a member function SaveAs() on a non-object in D:\www\wwwroot\com_server.php on line 18

and each time I run the page, there is a new WINWORD progress.It must be halted when open the file.


Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that line 16 is the one from `SaveAs()` at:

```
   $document=$word->Documents->Open($file);
   $document->SaveAs($saveas,8);
```

As you told on the comment for
Sometimes the `$word->Documents->Open()` gives that error; try with something like `$word->ActiveDocument` if you have previously opened it, or try:

```
    $word->Documents->Add() 
$word->ActiveDocument->open()
```

And then, try the save statement. Looks like you haven't been able to open it correctly. I haven't tested this in a while, so give it a shot. Also, remember to don't leave parenthesis on sentences such as `print` (but curly braces), and to null your object when you have finished.

If neither of this works, check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff836084.aspx) for an extensive explanation of the `expression.SaveAs2` method for Word. Maybe it will help. Good luck.